# Lost audio while converting video files in OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, video, file-conversion

I was using Lion's conversion feature to change .MPG video files to a compatible format (set by OS X). The files are now viewable in QuickTime and iMovie, but the audio is completely gone. Has anyone else come across a similar issue? Would I by chance be missing a codec required to convert .MPG files correctly? Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with muxed audio. See [here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1372) Also, you might try converting them with [Mpeg Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/), which is free software.

Comment: I'm assuming Apple doesn't support all conversion types, which is strange to me if they offer converting video files as an integrated feature. Thanks for your help!